# Backslash throws unexpected beginning of statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have this SQL Script for bulk loading my data:

```
INSERT INTO DeliveryMethod (deliveryMethod) 
VALUES ('Bicycle');
INSERT INTO DeliveryMethod (deliveryMethod) 
VALUES ('Car');
INSERT INTO DeliveryMethod (deliveryMethod) 
VALUES ('Van');
INSERT INTO DeliveryMethod (deliveryMethod) 
VALUES ('None');

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

# Load data into categories
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/CategoryData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Category
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(name)
SET categoryID = NULL; # Should trigger auto increment (or \r)

# Load data into package
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/PackageData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Package
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(price, itemName, category)
SET packageID = NULL; # Should trigger auto increment (or \r)

# Load data into address
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/AddressData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Address
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(buildingName, streetName, county, postcode)
SET addressID = NULL;

# Load data into packages
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/PackagesData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Packages
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(packagesID, package);

# Load data into branch
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/BranchData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Branch
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(branchName, address, headOfficeID, managerID, deliveryMethods)
SET branchID = NULL;

# Load data into consignment
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/ConsignmentData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Consignment
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(dispatchDate, consignmentType, branch, deliveryAddressID, returnAddressID, packages)
SET trackingID = NULL;

# Load data into DeliveryMethods
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/DeliveryMethodsData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.DeliveryMethods
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(deliveryMethodID, deliveryMethod);

# Load data into Employee
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/EmployeeData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Employee
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(NIN, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, emailAddress, mobileNo, salary, branchID, supervisorID, address)
SET staffNo = NULL;

# Load data into CustomerConsignments
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/CustomerConsignmentsData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.CustomerConsignments
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(consignmentsID, consignment);

# Load data into Customer
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/CustomerData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Customer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r'
(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, emailAddress, mobileNo, customerBranchID, address, consignments)
SET customerID = NULL;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

However with this said... I'm getting this error here for some reason when i put it into my relational schema:

> Static analysis:
>
> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 0) Unexpected beginning of
>   statement. (near "\" at position 0) Unexpected beginning of statement.
>   (near "r" at position 1) SQL query:
>
> \r LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4/PackageData.txt'
>   REPLACE INTO TABLE CourierDB.Package FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES
>   STARTING BY '(' TERMINATED BY ')\r' (price, itemName, category) SET
>   packageID = NULL
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\r LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   'C:/Users/ryank/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/DBMS-CW/R4' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `#` is not a comment character in mysql - use `--`.

Comment: @Kenney thanks for the tip, but that doesn't solve my issue

Comment: How's phpMyAdmin figure in to this; did it do the export, the import, or both? Which phpMyAdmin versions? Which MySQL/MariaDB versions were used for both export and import? Can you post the first few lines of your `PackageData.txt` file, obscuring any sensitive information such as hostname or user accounts.